# Postgres- "ERROR: generation expression is not immutable" why is my expression not immutable?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, immutability

I am trying to create an index for text search in Postgres, but I keep getting an error when I create generated tsvector column.

```
ERROR:  generation expression is not immutable
SQL state: 42P17
```

I have a text "title" column and text[] "authors" column. I am trying to combine the two to create a tsvector column

Here is the code that's getting the error

```
ALTER TABLE book
    ADD COLUMN tscol tsvector
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_tsvector(title || ' ' || immutable_array_to_string(coalesce(authors, '{}'), ' '))) STORED;
```

Code for immutable_array_to_string function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION immutable_array_to_string(text[], text) 
    RETURNS text as $$ SELECT array_to_string($1, $2); $$ 
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are calling `to_tsvector` without a `regconfig`, so the default one is used. In such case, the function is only `stable`. If you want it to be immutable, you must pass the `regconfig`.

```
to_tsvector('english',title || ' ' || immutable_array_to_string(coalesce(authors, '{}'), ' '))
```

PS: you can call `\df+ to_tsvector` to see the volatility of the function with different signatures.

Comment: Thank you!!!  I see my mistake now. Also thanks for \df+ to_tsvector tip :)))